# Calculating mean index value of raster for grid cell map using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have a raster index map and and also a polygon fishnet. I would like to assign mean index value into the grid cells.

How can I do that in ArcMap?

[image]

Comment: When you say "assign mean index value into grid cells", are you asking to compute and then assign the mean of the raster cell values for each polygon of your fishnet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "grid cells" you mean the fishnet polygons, then use the [Zonal Statistics as Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) with the following parameters:

```
Input raster or feature zone data = your fishnet
Zone field = a unique ID field in the fishnet
Input value raster = your ECI index raster
Output table = output table
Ignore NoData = ticked
Statistics type = MEAN
```

Then use the zone field to join the output table back to the fishnet using either the Add Join tool or the Join Fields tool.

[image]

Comment: Great suggestion! Thanks a lot.